# gtk3 scrolled window size, with gtkbox inside and buttons inside after resize

Tags: c, gtk

Hello i am having problems to set a fixed size of a scrolled windows.

Add the beginning the size of the scrolled windows is set

```
gtk_widget_set_size_request (scrolled_window, 150, 0);
```

Then i tried

```
gtk_widget_set_hexpand (scrolled_window,FALSE);
```

But when i resize the window the scrolled windows changes his width, with the buttons inside of her.

The packing of the buttons to the gbox i did it like this

```
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box_button), boton_527000_57888, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
```

I can figure out how to resolve it. i tried searching around the web but was not successfull

Comment: I suggest you install Glade and create a window that does exactly what you want. After you know how Gtk works, you could still create your window with code. Alternatively, post your complete code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the answer is here, i must use gtkgrid because gtkgrid doesn't expand the widgets.

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkGrid.html